# Cannot access the file '....docx' because it is being used by another process. When accessing the MS Word Doc Saved through VSTO Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I've written a VSTO-Add In for MS Word which saves the document on cloud instead of saving it locally.

To achieve this I'm doing as follows:

1. When user is saving MS Word Document (Ctrl + S), I'm saving it to a temporary location
2. From the saved location (D:\Temp\xxx-yyy-zzz.docx) I'm uploading the document on server.

I'm getting below error:
**The process cannot access the file 'D:\Temp\xxx-yyy-zzz.docx' because it is being used by another process.**
when trying to access the file to upload on server.

Following is the code I'm using it:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wdApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
object saveFileName = "D:\Temp\xxx-yyy-zzz.docx";
object fileFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault; 
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

wdDoc.SaveAs2(FileName: ref saveFileName, FileFormat: ref fileFormat);
```

When trying to read the saved file. 'Can not access .......being used by another process' Exception is thrown. Below is the code

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\Temp\xxx-yyy-zzz.docx");
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ole Automation tends to mimmic the UI so `SaveAs2` most likely does the same as **File.Save as**.  Sure it saves the document but it also `keeps it open`, only the filename has changed

Comment: Thanks Micky! Let me check.

Comment: Mong, I'm using wdDoc.SaveAs2( and want the Word Doc to remain Open. If considering it you could suggest something should be great.

Comment: ok but then why do you want to read it again? don't you have already all the file content in memory in your code present?

Comment: Mong, Thanks for your reply.
It's just like working with MS Word.
1) New Document
2) Write Something and Save
3) It asks for File Name (here I'm saving on local drive and uploading it on server)
4) Continue to work on the same doc
5) When document is closed, I updated it once again on the server.

Comment: "here I'm saving on local drive and uploading it on server" But if you cannot move the file while it is open, I don't see any other way but to close it first, then move then reopen it again for editing

Comment: There are a lot of unknown areas - where and when do you read the file content?